# RxJs: How to combine two observable into a new observable with different type

Tags: rxjs, side-effects, ngrx-effects

I'm very new to `RxJs` and `NgRx store` , I'm want to create an `@Effect` with combination of two observables (very difficult to explain):

My interfaces looks like:

```
export interface ProductDetails {
  product: Product;
  productBody: ProductBody;
}

export interface ProductBody{
  id: string;
  body: string;
}
```

I'm trying to create a new object`productDetails` and set it's properties.
properties are `product` which `payload` has `product` and `productBody` which gets it from `productService(id)` (It returns `observable<productBody>`)

This effect should return `observable<productDetails>`

```
   @Effect()
  getProductDetails$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(ProductActions.GET_STEP)
    .map(action => action.payload)
    .flatMap(s => {
      let body;
      this.productService.getStepBody(s.id).subscribe(x => body = x);
      return Observable.of({
        step: s,
        productBody: body
      });
    })
    .map(res => this.productActions.getProductDetailsSuccess(res));
```

this returns:`Object {productBody: undefined, product: Object}`

I understand why is returning `undefined` for `productBody` but not sure how to fix it. I tried using `zip`, `switchMap` and etc but no chance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can do.

- You want to `flatMap` over the original observable to get the `payload.id` to give it to the `getStepBody` observable.
- Then, inside the `flatMap`, you want to `map` on the `getStepBody` observable to return a new value that is a composite object of the `payload` and the response of the `getStepBody`.
- Finally `subscribe` to get the final result.

It looks something like this:

```
getProductDetails$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(ProductActions.GET_STEP)
    .map(action => action.payload)
    .flatMap(payload => this.productService.getStepBody(payload.id).map(body => ({step: payload, productBody: body})))
    .subscribe(res => this.productActions.getProductDetailsSuccess(res));  //res is an object of {step: payload, productBody: body}
```

If you are not wanting to return the whole object into a single function in the `subscribe` function, you could destructure the values to make them easier to consume separately.  To that change the `subscribe` line to:

```
.subscribe(({step, body}) => {//do something with each value});
```